# My PHP Contact form is not working correctly. Sends partial information

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am new to PHP but have a site that I need to go live and I cant get the form to work.

Basically what it does is send JUST whats in the "message" field. All other fields are blank for some reason. Also, if possible, I would like help getting it to put a confirmation of "sent mail" without redirecting to a new page, but rather just a pop up message in the form itself.

So here is the code.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Which class are you interested in?" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="What is the best number to you reach you?" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and here is the PHP

```
<?php

$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Class = $_POST['class'];
$Phone = $_POST['phone'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: **** Site'; 
$to = '**********@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Message from **** Site';

$body = "From: $Name\n E-Mail: $Email\n Class: $Class\n Phone: $Phone\n      Message:\n $Message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
}

?>
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume your HTML and PHP are on the same page, which is "index.php"? Could we also see a sample of the email message it sends (just the text)? Also, try var_dump'ing the $_POST variable before your PHP starts doing anything, just to double check if it receives everything in good order.

Answer (score 0):

Made one change to this code,

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="mail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="class" placeholder="Which class are you interested in?" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="What is the best number to you reach you?" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

And check the PHP file,

```
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Class = $_POST['class'];
$Phone = $_POST['phone'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: **** Site'; 
$to = '**********@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Message from **** Site';

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

All the variables are being passed.

For having the answer in the same page without redirecting, use jQuery AJAX requests like this example. Use Javascript. http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

I'll post the answer for your solution if you still have issues with the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `$_POST` values inside the `if ($_POST['submit'])` check.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {   
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $Class = $_POST['text'];
    $Phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $Message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: **** Site'; 
    $to = '**********@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from **** Site';
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
}
?>
```

For submit the form without page refresh use `jQuery.post()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/